# Problem with columns for model fit and predict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, model, pipeline

I have this pipeline

```
sklearn.set_config(transform_output='pandas')

make_column_transformer = partial(make_column_transformer, remainder='passthrough')
drop = make_column_transformer(('drop', ['CAMPAÑA']))
encoder = make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore'), ['remainder__ID_FINCA', 'remainder__ID_ZONA', 'remainder__ID_ESTACION']))

preprocessing = make_pipeline(drop, encoder)
```

Late this model works well:

```
pipe = Pipeline([('preprocessing', preprocessing),('modelo',DecisionTreeRegressor())])

parameters = {'modelo__criterion': ['squared_error', 'absolute_error'],
              'modelo__max_depth':[3,7,11,15,20,30,50],
              'modelo__min_samples_split':[2,7,11],
              'modelo__min_samples_leaf':[5,10,15,20],
              'modelo__ccp_alpha'   : [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}

search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = pipe, 
                            param_distributions=parameters, 
                            n_iter     = 20,
                            cv=RepeatedKFold(n_splits = 5, n_repeats = 5, random_state = 0),
                            verbose    = 1,
                            n_jobs = -1,
                            random_state = 0,
                            return_train_score = True)

search.fit(X_Train, y_Train)
print(search.best_params_, end='\n\n')

dtr = search.best_estimator_
description = 'Decision Tree regression_All'
show_results(description, dtr, X_Train, y_Train, X_Test, y_Test)
```

But I'm trying to fit and predict with another model with the important features like that:

```
relevant_feat_20 = preprocessing.transform(X_Train).columns[np.argsort(dtr.steps[1][1].feature_importances_)[:-20:-1]].to_list()
transformers = [('preprocessing', preprocessing, relevant_feat_20)]
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers)
pipe = Pipeline([('preprocessing', preprocessor), ('modelo', DecisionTreeRegressor())])

parameters = {'modelo__criterion': ['squared_error', 'absolute_error'],
              'modelo__max_depth':[3,7,11,15,20,30,50],
              'modelo__min_samples_split':[2,7,11],
              'modelo__min_samples_leaf':[5,10,15,20],
              'modelo__ccp_alpha'   : [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}

search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = pipe, 
                            param_distributions=parameters, 
                            n_iter     = 20,
                            cv=RepeatedKFold(n_splits = 5, n_repeats = 5, random_state = 0),
                            verbose    = 1,
                            n_jobs = -1,
                            random_state = 0,
                            return_train_score = True)

search.fit(X_Train, y_Train)
print(search.best_params_, end='\n\n')

dtr = search.best_estimator_
description = 'Decision Tree regression_20'
show_results(description, dtr, X_Train, y_Train, X_Test, y_Test)
```

But i'm haveing problems with the columns like that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 448, in _get_column_indices
    col_idx = all_columns.get_loc(col)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3804, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'remainder__remainder__SUPERFICIE'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 686, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 401, in fit
    Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 359, in _fit
    X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py", line 349, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 893, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_set_output.py", line 142, in wrapped
    data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 724, in fit_transform
    self._validate_column_callables(X)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 426, in _validate_column_callables
    transformer_to_input_indices[name] = _get_column_indices(X, columns)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 456, in _get_column_indices
    raise ValueError("A given column is not a column of the dataframe") from e
ValueError: A given column is not a column of the dataframe
```

The thing is that with the first pipeline i do one hot encoding creating new columns, later i try the importance columns from the first model on the X_Train set, some columns do not exist, so how can I insert the feature selection by importance of the previous model inside the second pipeline.